# Should I hide decorator from the trace of the decorated function? (python)

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, traceback

I created a library with decorator. It allows to run seamlessly any function in a separate thread and get timeout exception even that function stuck in TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE due to IO to the broken NFS or other nasty problem.

Now I'm working with exception handling. I'm passing exception from the thread back to the caller thread and reraising it again.

Right now trace (if it happens inside decorated function) looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 11, in <module>
    foo()
  File "1.py", line 9, in foo
    boo()
  File "thread_timeout/__init__.py", line 116, in inner_worker
    result = wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "1.py", line 6, in boo
    file('/fdf','r')
```

If I remove decorator it looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 11, in <module>
    foo()
  File "1.py", line 9, in foo
    boo()
  File "1.py", line 6, in boo
    file('/fdf','r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/fdf'
```

Question: should I try to hide decorator from the trace or not?

Library code is available here: [https://github.com/amarao/thread_timeout/blob/master/thread_timeout/**init**.py](https://github.com/amarao/thread_timeout/blob/master/thread_timeout/__init__.py)

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to hide it?

Comment: Because decorator trying to hide any traces of 'multithreading'. For user it should be like 'add decorator and nothing changed, except for the timeout exception if timeout happens'. Additional line in the trace is disturbing, when user trying to debug own issues. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: Trying to hide any traces of errors is not a good idea.  You want the decorator to be transparent when it's working, not when it fails.  If you hide the decorator, how will you be able to find bugs caused by the decorator itself, or its interaction with the code using it?

Comment: It is not 'fail in decorator'. I'm carrying exception from the user code and I don't want to be in the middle of affairs. Any bugs or exceptions in the decorator code itself will be raised as normal exceptions. I'm talking only about exception in the decorated function, not in the decorator itself.

Comment: If you aren't already, you should consider taking advantage of [venusian](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/venusian/en/latest/) for your framework decorators..